# How do i make a working newline to .txt file?

Tags: php

Can someone please help me make newlines into the .txt?

```
$file = 'a.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= "'.$test.'\r\ntest";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Those **doesnt** work for me:

```
\n

\r\n

$n = "" . PHP_EOL;

$n = "
";
```

Comment: How do you create the `.txt` ?

Comment: have you try `<br>` ?

Comment: @otezz <br> didnt work.

Comment: Show us some code that we can use to reproduce the problem you're having. Don't make us guess.

Comment: @Raptor I dont create a .txt the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
        $myfile = fopen("yourtxt file", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, "some text"."\n");
        fclose($myfile);
```

According to your code, try below :

```
$test = 'some content';

$file = 'a.txt';
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $test."\ntest";
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Comment: didnt work ( fwrite($myfile, "some text"."\n"."test"."\n"."test");)

Comment: @anon updated my code..please try again and let me know

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents("test.txt","test1\ntest2\ntest3");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"\n"`. `'\n'` does not work.